# Registering Iceberg Day Partition Transform UDFs in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-iceberg

I am looking to apply Iceberg's same hidden `day` and `year` partitioning to a DataFrame in the same way as we apply the `bucket` partitioning. https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-writes/.

Iceberg provides `IcebergSpark.registerbucketUdf`; I'm looking for the same capability for Iceberg's other hidden partition transforms.

Specifically, for the `Day` transform, I want something like

```
import org.apache.iceberg.transforms.Transforms
import org.apache.iceberg.types.Types

val day = Transforms.day[Timestamp](Types.TimestampType.withZone())
def dayFunc(ts: Timestamp): Integer = day.apply(ts)
val dayUdf = spark.udf.register("ts_day", dayFunc _)
...

df.withColumn("dayPartition", expr(s"ts_day(${timestampCol})"))
```

However, the UDF cannot be applied. Error: `class java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long`. I believe the `Day` transform should [return](https://iceberg.apache.org/spec/#partition-transforms) the days since 1970-01-01.

I've tried a few combinations here and am not getting the right results. I can attempt to truncate dates myself, but wish to use *exactly* what Iceberg is using in-memory for partition management.